# Sorting an array displayed with ngFor applies void animation state

Tags: angular, sorting, animation, ngfor, angular-animations

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let user of users; trackBy: identify; index as i" [@anim]="user.id" (@anim.done)="test($event)">
    {{user.name}} (@{{user.id}})
</li>
</ul>

  constructor() {
    this.change1();
  }

  change1(): void {
    this.users = [user1, user2, user3, user4, user5];
  }
  change2(): void {
    this.users = [user2, user1, user3, user4, user5];
  }

  identify(index: number, item: User) {
    return item.id;
  }

  test(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }


const user1 = { id: 1, name: 'one' };
const user2 = { id: 2, name: 'two' };
const user3 = { id: 3, name: 'three' };
const user4 = { id: 4, name: 'four' };
const user5 = { id: 5, name: 'five' };
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h7ohwc?file=src/app/app.component.html

This example shows the problem. We have an array using trackBy + each element has animations. After sorting the array (button change2) in the console you can see that element 2 changes state from 2 to void. Is it possible to get state 2 if it does not change? Why is it becoming void?